# 3D bend equation derivation.

Tags: trigonometry, 3d

This is how the bend work: (The number is the angle)

[image: bend]

I was searching for an equation to bend an object in a specific axis and I found one,It worked pretty well,but unfortunately I don't know why it works.

The equation is :

$$
x'= (x-\frac { 1 }{ z\theta  } )\times\cos  ({ z\theta  })+\frac { 1 }{ z\theta  } \\ y'= y\\ z'= -(x-\frac { 1 }{ z\theta  } )\times\sin  ({ z\theta  })
$$

I want to know how they got this equation,or at least a simple explanation.
and if it is already a known equation,what is its name?

Comment: you are using a non clear reference system and notation: please explain better

Comment: @GCab you mean the equations?

Comment: yes, in the equations, how are the axes orientated with respect to the "bar" ? , why 3D ? derivative vs. $\theta$ or what ?

Comment: @GCab the Y axis is the axis that is going inward or perpendicular to the screen plane.
3D because it can take place in the 3 axis by 2 other equations similar to this.
By derivation,I mean how did this equation came from,how to prove it?

Comment: What is x? Is it the height?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN No,the z is the height.

Comment: Did you consider trying to see the rod as an arc of a circle with a radius getting smaller and smaller?

Comment: No,I don't see how is this relevant.